# How does ethereum consensus clients agree on validators in the committees and proposer for slots?

Tags: eth-2.0

As I understand, the consensus beacon nodes on the network would need to have a common, shared knowledge of the committees, members of the committees and proposers.

Questions:

1. Is the above understanding correct?
2. How do they consensus on these types of information is achieved
   among beacon nodes?

Thanks in advance